# Delphi Format() analog at C++

Tags: c++, qt, delphi, boost

There's project in Delphi by Windows, whitch should be rewrite in C++ (Qt) by Linux and formating string in C-style:

`String res := Format('%2d''%2d"', [minute, seconds]);`

So, it should format to string two integers minute and seconds for longtitude or latitude. I've tried to use `Qtring("%1%2).arg(minute, 2, 10).arg(seconds, 2, 10);`, but it's not totally correct (and I can't to shield ' and " for units). So is there tool in Qt or e.g. boost for formating string in C-style?

Comment: Have you tried using string streams or printf?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis good advice, but my task is change project in C++, not stay at Delphi)

Comment: @AlexeiBarnes printf returns number of symbols, but I need a string.

Comment: [snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: @Padmelina Simply pass it a char* buffer for it to output into: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: I think by "shield" you mean escape. That is done with \ in C++. I.e. to output `"` you write `"\""` in your code.

Comment: @UliGerhardt yes, thank you for help

Comment: `<Aaargh>` I mean the new upcoming Delphi for Windows 32, Windows 64, OS X, iOS, Android and Linux.

Comment: C++ standard facility is [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) but behavior differs from `Format`. Please be more specific on requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Delphi code

```
String res := Format('%2d''%2d"', [minutes, seconds]);
```

has the following Qt equivalent:

```
auto res = QStringLiteral("%1'%2\"").arg(minutes,2).arg(seconds,2);
```

> I can't to shield [escape] ' and " for units

You should read about [string literals in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). This is basic C++ and nothing to do with Qt specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can simply use string concatenation and `std::to_string`.

```
#include <string>
int myInt = 42;
std::string myString = "hello";    
std::string res = "myInt equals " + std::to_string(myInt) + ", myString equals " + myString";

// res == "myInt equals 42, myString equals hello"
```

Alternatively, you could use `std::ostringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>
std::ostringstream s;
s << "myInt equals ";
s << myInt;
s << ", myString equals " << myString;
std::string res = s.str();
```

If you really need to use traditional string formatting, the library fmt has what you need (https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt):

```
std::string res = fmt::sprintf("myString = %s", myString");
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question, and it's far from idiomatic C++.

Comment: The part with libfmt precisely answers the question (at least if I understood the question correctly).